# Psychology of timbre processing

Tags: perception, music, hearing

Are there any studies concerning the psychological aspects of timbre processing in the brain, e.g. while listening to music? In particular, can any lower-level correlates be discerned when trying to answer questions like:

- what makes particular timbres more pleasing than others? (e.g. a trumpet vs pure sine wave)
- what accounts for different preferences between people? (e.g. preference for piano sound over trumpet)

Comment: I think this is a great question (I'm a "lower-level correlates" fan, myself), but I think it's going to be hard to take something highly abstract like taste preferences ("Do I like that?" can be a decision based on a very large and multimodal feature space) and map them to neurophysiological processes, like we could for tonal processing and the like.

Comment: (someone is perfectly welcome to prove me wrong on that)

Comment: I Mostly agree with Chuck.  But I think the physics of the timbre are important to decomposing timbre so that we can talk about what different characteristics create what different effects.  The major characteristics of timbre are: attack, decay, and sustain.  They basically describe the shape of the envelope.  Also important are the harmonics of the instrument (for instance, on a violin, the strings themselves have harmonics but the body of the violin also resonates).  I think part of the richness of the violin as how intense the timbre is.  The strings are constantly being perturbed.

Comment: @Xurtio Sure, that would certainly be true if you could extract which physical features make those notes unique and examine them objectively, recognizing that the quantity "timbre" (e.g.,note on a piano vs. note on a violin, as the Wiki example cites)  itself is likely measurable.  The higher-level "judgement" of that complex quantity is likely still too abstract, though.

Comment: I think you probably could to some extent.  If you have people judge the quality of several timbres and see if there is a particular trend for timbres with sharper attacks for instance.

Comment: For judgments, you could have one group rate some fixed set of qualities fir each timbre and have another group answer in their own words in a paragraph, then perform quantitative phenomenology analysis.   The second group would help avoid a priming bias.

Comment: @Xurtio It's indisputable that it could be studied.  I'm just concerned with trying to establish lower-level correlates of "I like tubas because they remind me of the time I played in marching band on a cold day during the state football championships" would be difficult (so in terms of his second bullet point).

Comment: Ah yeah, I agree.  Too much emergent complexity involved with the second bullet point which means lots of degeneracy

Answer (score 3):

For a general discussion of neural correlates of music perception, check out the review by Koelsch et al (2005).

Menon et al (2002) provide a starting point for learning about neural correlates of timbre processing. I quote the abstract. But have a look at the article for more info

> Timbre is a major structuring force in music and one of the most
>   important and ecologically relevant features of auditory events. We
>   used sound stimuli selected on the basis of previous
>   psychophysiological studies to investigate the neural correlates of
>   timbre perception. Our results indicate that both the **left and right
>   hemispheres are involved in timbre processing**, challenging the
>   conventional notion that the elementary attributes of musical
>   perception are predominantly lateralized to the right hemisphere.
>   **Signiﬁcant timbre-related brain activation was found in well-de- ﬁned
>   regions of posterior Heschl’s gyrus and superior temporal sulcus,
>   extending into the circular insular sulcus**. Although the extent of
>   activation was not signiﬁcantly different between left and right
>   hemispheres, temporal lobe activations were signiﬁcantly posterior in
>   the left, compared to the right, hemisphere, suggesting a functional
>   asymmetry in their respective contributions to timbre processing. The
>   implications of our ﬁndings for music processing in particular and
>   auditory processing in general are discussed.

Halpern et al (2004) provide another relevant study:

> The generality of findings implicating secondary auditory areas in
>   auditory imagery was tested by using a timbre imagery task with fMRI.
>   Another aim was to test whether activity in supplementary motor area
>   (SMA) seen in prior studies might have been related to
>   subvocalization. Participants with moderate musical background were
>   scanned while making similarity judgments about the timbre of heard or
>   imagined musical instrument sounds. The critical control condition was
>   a visual imagery task. The pattern of judgments in perceived and
>   imagined conditions was similar, suggesting that perception and
>   imagery access similar cognitive representations of timbre. As
>   expected, judgments of heard timbres, relative to the visual imagery
>   control, activated primary and secondary auditory areas with some
>   right-sided asymmetry. Timbre imagery also activated secondary
>   auditory areas relative to the visual imagery control, although less
>   strongly, in accord with previous data. Significant overlap was
>   observed in these regions between perceptual and imagery conditions.
>   Because the visual control task resulted in deactivation of auditory
>   areas relative to a silent baseline, we interpret the timbre imagery
>   effect as a reversal of that deactivation. Despite the lack of an
>   obvious subvocalization component to timbre imagery, some activity in
>   SMA was observed, suggesting that SMA may have a more general role in
>   imagery beyond any motor component.

#### References

- Menon, V., Levitin, D. J., Smith, B. K., Lembke, A., Krasnow, B. D., Glazer, D., ... & McAdams, S. (2002). Neural correlates of timbre change in harmonic sounds. Neuroimage, 17(4), 1742-1754. [PDF](http://spin.ecn.purdue.edu/fmri/PDFLibrary/MenonV_NI_2002_17_1742_1754.pdf)
- Halpern, A. R., Zatorre, R. J., Bouffard, M., & Johnson, J. A. (2004). Behavioral and neural correlates of perceived and imagined musical timbre. Neuropsychologia, 42(9), 1281-1292. [PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.198.9746&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- Koelsch, S., & Siebel, W. A. (2005). Towards a neural basis of music perception. Trends in cognitive sciences, 9(12), 578-584. Koelsch, S., & Siebel, W. A. (2005). Towards a neural basis of music perception. Trends in cognitive sciences, 9(12), 578-584. [HTML](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3114071/)